# ioslides: place title logo on the right side

Tags: css, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm working on a presentation with ioslides (Rmarkdown). Since the corporate design rules for our university state that the logo should be on the right side (so the two faces look into the document) I'ld be happy if someone can help me with adjusting the ioslide theme via css or in the pandoc template.

The image and grey box should come in from the right side. I wasn't able to do that. All I could do was making the grey so long that is reaches the right side (which moves the logo as well cause it is relatively placed to the grey boxes right end as it seems to me).

Here is some CSS code I already found and experimented with:

```
.gdbar img {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  margin: 8px 8px;
}

.gdbar {
  width: 90% !important; # with 250px instead of 90% it produces the image posted below
  height: 170px !important;
}
```

This is the code produced after kniting: https://box.hu-berlin.de/f/d3d9e907fcef41a0bbf1/

I don't understand where the gdbar code resides in the first place. Would be happy about a hint here as well.

Edit: I have now this CSS setup and am almost done. Only the logo should be shifted a little bit to the left.

```
.gdbar img {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  margin: 8px 8px;
}

.gdbar {
  width: 250px !important;
  height: 170px !important;
}

aside.gdbar {
  left: initial;
  right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background-position: right;
}
```

Best regards, Simon

[image]

Comment: Usually setting ```right: 0``` would do the job but then your image must be ```position: relative``` and parent must be wider so image has room to move around. You need to share CSS code of parent elements as well to help us understand the full context or link to your project if it's online.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. I've added a codeto the link of the produced .html file. It's not clear to me where the .gdbar settings come from in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element has `left: -1px` property what makes sure it's always on the left. If you set left to initial:

```
aside.gdbar {
 left: initial;
 right: 0;
}
```

or you remove this `left` setting then your element will move to the right.

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said now it is on the right side. Have you a soloutin on how to invert the animation as well? When I shift it to the right, the animation should start at the right as well.

Comment: @Famondir try adding: ```background-position: right;``` to ```slides > slide.current .gdbar```
You will have to play around with border-radius as well :)

Comment: Hm. This has an interesting effect. I'll try further. Where do you know from what class names the objects have? When I inspect the page there is very little about the gbar. Does the slide_config.json play a role here? If so - where is this anyway?

Comment: I have copied your HTML code into fiddle so I can inspect it (because HTML code doesn't tell me much) and then I just look into the styles panel in dev tools and enable/disable or look into CSS properties that I think might result in the given outcome and add my own css properties as well. Web Inspectors are truly powerful :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have adjusted my used css code above. The last thing I have to do is shift the logo to the left a bit.

Comment: @Famondir no problem, remember to check the accepted answer mark (if it answers your question of course ;))

EDIT: you can set `right: 10px` or any other value.

Comment: the only class where the `right` property has an effect is aside.gdbar. Then the image AND the bar are shifted to the left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236022/discussion-between-famondir-and-wiktor).